# ASP.NET Form Submission From Standard HTML Submit and No JavaScript

Tags: asp.net

Can you do a form submission to a different page in ASP.NET without using a cross page postback, from a non ASP.NET control, and with no Javascript!?

*Im using ASP.NET with a global form in the masterpage

*My site needs to work with no Javascript and I want to avoid URL paramaters.

*I'm using an  which will open up a new page for a particular record in my application.

*I want to use the name of the input button to get the RecordId to edit and post it to a new page using HTTP POST as opposed to an URL param.

CAN THIS BE DONE!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand, so I'm sorry if I'm way off.

You maybe able to add a checkbox, whose ID is the RecordID, and then when you do the HTTP POST you can loop through the checkboxes and see which one is checked.  There are probably way more elegant solutions though.

Answer (score 0):

Set the Post Page and the target (to open new window):

```
this.Form.Action = "YourNextPage.aspx";
this.Form.Target = "_blank";
```

Then, get the values in the next page:

```
this.Request.Form[...
```